# window.scrollTo doesn't work in phonegap for IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ios6

I am calling:

```
window.scrollTo(0,this.stateModel.get("scrollY"));
```

in phonegap in a view's render function.

This code works on the android emulator, but not on the iPhone 6.0 emulator.

Is there any reason scrollTo wouldn't work on IOS?

Comment: What are the values of: this.stateModel.get("scrollY")
or even: this.stateModel
and: this

Comment: `code console.log("Scrolling to: " + this.stateModel.get("scrollY"));`   yields: `code [LOG] Scrolling to: 620`

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this as well. As a workaround, I simply created an anchor element in the desired position and then invoked a click event on a hidden anchor link.

```
<a class="anchor" href="#desiredLocation" style="display: none;"></a>
<a id="desiredLocation"></a>
```

jQuery code...

```
$(".anchor").click();
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it provides the same behavior.